# Use a single structure in C to store different structures and access them as index

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to do an Agenda with a structure, the thing is, I want it to be able to  store 10 appointments and be able to access them to check them. I'm trying to do it without writing a file and reading it, I don't mind everything erases itself after the program ends.

```
struct Agenda{
    char cita[40];
    char fecha[8];
    char hora[5];
};

void agregar_cita(int *num_c){
    static struct Agenda x;
    printf("Ingrese la cita: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(x.cita);
    printf("\nIngrese la fecha: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(x.fecha);
    printf("\nIngrese la hora: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(x.hora);
}
```

I want to pass "*num_c" as a parameter and add 1 to it everytime you make a new appointment, but I can't get to access it after that.

*I'm sorry about the spanish, the function is just to add an appointment. Oh and try to use not so advanced things since I'm just recently starting to program please and thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use `gets` (which is obsolete and removed from recent standards) but use `fgets`. And call `fflush(NULL)` not `fflush(stdin)`

Answer (score 1):

Since you want *multiple* `Agenda` objects, indexed by an integer, you should declare an array.  You can access elements by index, and since you're passing a pointer to the index, you can also update it from the function:

```
void agregar_cita(int *num_c){
    static struct Agenda x[10];

    printf("Ingrese la cita: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    gets(x[*num_c].cita);
    printf("\nIngrese la fecha: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    gets(x[*num_c].fecha);
    printf("\nIngrese la hora: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    gets(x[*num_c].hora);
    *num_c += 1;
}
```

Note also that it's not useful to flush `stdin`, but it looks like what you really wanted was to flush `stdout` to ensure that your prompts appear (as shown).

Comment: My teacher told me fflush stdin would work to ensure the prompts appeared and it seemed to work, what's the difference between flushing stdin and stdout?

Comment: And also what should I do after declaring the array like you did to access it? Like if I have my main I should just type `x[num_c].cita` in a `printf` and that's it?

Comment: Your main function cannot access a variable declared inside a different function, even if the variable is `static`.  Move the variable declaration outside the function, and put it at the top of the file, just after the definition of type `struct Agenda`.  Then all of the functions in the same file will be able to access it.

Comment: `stdin` and `stdout` are (or at least may be) different streams.  The latter is the default stream for output, used, for example, by `printf()`.  You should flush the stream to which you wrote the data -- that is, `stdout`.  If flushing `stdin` happens to have the effect you wanted then that is an implementation and circumstancial detail on which you should not rely.

Comment: @AngelAvila, the common way to display a prompt is to write it to `stderr` which is unbuffered by default, so there's no need to flush at all.

Comment: @mafso, except that unbuffered *by default* is not the same as definitely unbuffered.  Moreover, choosing `stderr` over `stdout` on the basis of buffering is terribly poor style.  The choice between `stdout` and `stderr` should be made based on the nature of what is being written.  Only error / diagnostic messages should go to `stderr`.  That allows the user to separate these from normal program output.  I disagree that what you describe is "the common way".

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I agree that `stderr` being unbuffered isn't a reason to use it for a prompt, just that the whole problem doesn't arise when writing to `stderr` (re-reading my comment, I admit it could be interpreted this way). Afaik, it's always unbuffered as long as your code doesn't change this. Every shell I know prints its prompt to `stderr` (the only programme writing its prompt to `stdout` I found after trying a few is GNU parted). If I want to log the output, `./foo | tee log` should do IMO, and I'm not interested in prompts in such a log.

Comment: @mafso, `stderr` may easily be buffered without specific action by the program itself.  This is partially a function of how the program is started.  If, for instance, its `stderr` is a copy of its `stdin` (which can easily be accomplished via I/O redirection in the shell) then `stderr` will likely be buffered.